# CKEditor plugin rendering different in WYSIWYG and source mode

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm starting to develop a plugin for [CKEditor](http://docs.cksource.com/) that needs to be used to insert some *HTML* snippets in a web page. This is done. Nonetheless I also need to include some special items when switching to *WYSIWYG* mode (e.g. something more or less similar to *Show Blocks* plugin, but not just using styles since I need some elements included in there). So my question is :

How could I include extra items or styles (e.g. to hide parts of the contents in WYSIWYG mode) in *WYSIWYG* view without altering *HTML* output ?

If someone could provide some information about a working (maybe simple) example, I'd also appreciate your help.

PS: If you need to know further details please ask, but for instance assume inserted raw *HTML* code is

```
<div class="xxx">Hello world !</div>
```

... but in *WYSIWYG* mode need to display a link on top of it that pops up an alert and toggles dotted border.

Comment: ...the completion of sentences?

Answer (score 0):

About injecting *CSS* classes in *WYSIWYG* mode, use [addCss](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#addCss) function.

About creating fake elements in *WYSIWYG* mode ... I think I can solve the problem using context menu instead.